# How does time influence moveit motion planning?

Tags: pid, moveit, ros-melodic, ros-control, motionplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I just got started with ROS and moveit! to make my robot arm plan some movements. Ultimately I would like to optimize the speed of the executed movements by tuning the actuator's PID parameters. However, I noticed that moveit also keeps track of the time it takes to execute a motion. Now I worry that moveit factors in time somehow when it decides what trajectory to follow for the motion plannning, which would lead to it planning different motion trajectories when I start optimizing my PID's/execution time. I looked around on the internet but couldn't find any information about this.

So my question is: Does the motion execution time influence the planned trajectory of moveit? What influence does time have here?

Thank you for answering in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352431/how-does-time-influence-moveit-motion-planning?/) by [You RQT](https://answers.ros.org/users/54870/you-rqt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-05-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Now I worry that moveit factors in time somehow when it decides what trajectory to follow for the motion plannning,

If you're using the default planner (ie: OMPL), then it doesn't.

OMPL finds *paths*, not trajectories.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [You RQT](https://answers.ros.org/users/54870/you-rqt/) on 2020-05-17**:
Thank you for your reply! I'm using set_pose_target() function from MoveIt! and the FollowJointTrajectory control for all the actuators. Is it still a path if I use OMPL in that way?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-17**:
OMPL plans paths, not trajectories. It doesn't matter which way you ask Moveit to plan it, in the end it's OMPL (unless you've configured a different planner to be used).

**Comment by [You RQT](https://answers.ros.org/users/54870/you-rqt/) on 2020-05-17**:
Thanks a lot, it's much clearer now!

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2020-05-17**:
@gvdhoorn does any of the current planners in Moveit set velocities/accelerations for the joints or is this done in post-processing with e.g. Iterative Parabolic Time Parameterization or Iterative Spline Parameterization?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-18**:
Please don't post questions in comments under questions with already accepted answers.

Post a new question.

**Comment by [funky_watermelon](https://answers.ros.org/users/55046/funky_watermelon/) on 2020-05-28**:
@gvdhoorn I think it is still relevant for this question. But the path returned by .plan() of the moveit commander returns a message of the type: http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectoryPoint.html . How does the time_from_start get involved if ompl doesn't return it. This link also point to the time dependency of the moveit commander functions: https://books.google.nl/books?id=wY2RCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA353&vq=trajectory&hl=nl&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q&f=false

**Comment by [You RQT](https://answers.ros.org/users/54870/you-rqt/) on 2020-05-28**:
@funky_watermelon I think that is a very valid point and I'm interested to hear what @gvdhoorn thinks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-28**:
It may be relevant, but it's a different question (which I believe also has already been answered).

The OP's question was: "how does timing information influence path planning?"

Your question is: "where does the time info even come from?"

Those are two different questions, and accordingly, should be asked in different posts.